# WP_Query for Archive Page Date not work

Tags: wordpress, date, archive

I have edited my theme on archive.php for show only a specific post and exclude a post with specific meta_key:

```
$posts_to_exclude_args = array(
                    'meta_key' => 'vip_box',                
                    );
                    $posts_to_exclude = new WP_Query( $posts_to_exclude_args );
                    $to_exclude = array();
                    while ( $posts_to_exclude->have_posts() ) : $posts_to_exclude->the_post(); 
                        $to_exclude[] = $post->ID;
                    endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    $lastupdated_args = array(
                    'post__not_in' => $to_exclude,
                    'author__in'     => $author,
                    'category__in'   => $terms,
                    'posts_per_page' => 12,
                    'has_archive' => true,
                    'paged'          => $paged,                 
                    );
                    $lastupdated_loop = new WP_Query( $lastupdated_args );
                    query_posts( $lastupdated_args );
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

And its perfect but now if i open a date link/url  mywebsite.com/2017/06 it show all post and not only post in this date, why?.

Please can you help me?

Comment: On a side not you don't have to use `query_posts` after `WP_Query`. They do the same thing, but `WP_Query` is highly recommended, because it doesn't modify global variables, is safe to use anywhere and is more efficient at querying posts. The loop would just need to change to `<?php if ( $lastupdated_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $lastupdated_loop->have_posts() ) : $lastupdated_loop->the_post(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed with this code, but i think there is a best solution than this. =)

```
$year     = get_query_var('year');
                    $monthnum = get_query_var('monthnum');
                    $day      = get_query_var('day');

'date_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'year'     => $year,
                        'monthnum'    => $monthnum,  
                        'day'  => $day,  
                            ),
                        ),
                    );
```